# How to decelerate an AddForce slowly FIXED

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2d rigidbody that needs to glide to a stop. To move, I add a force to the rigidbody at the speed that I like, called `speedUp`, and I do not know how to make it glide to a stop. I tried adding an opposite force when I let go of the W key, but it stopped immediately. I need to find a way to make the "ship" decelerate to a stop after .5 seconds. I have found others asking this question, but none of the answers have worked for me and my specific code. Adding Drag does not work either, as I want to be able to move in other directions as well.

```
GameObject ship;
public Vector2 speedUp;
public Rigidbody2D shipRig;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    ship = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ship");
    shipRig = ship.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.W)) {
        shipRig.drag = 0;
        shipRig.AddForce(speedUp);
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp (KeyCode.W)) {
    }
```

Thanks to all of you!

EDIT!

I fixed it!!! Thanks all of you guys for your suggestions, all I did was change it from 'GetKeyDown' to 'GetKey' and it worked! I put the drag to 2 and the speed is 40px.

```
GameObject ship;
public Vector2 speedUp;
public Vector2 speedDown;
public Vector2 speedLeft;
public Vector2 speedRight;
public Rigidbody2D shipRig;

public Vector2 speed1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    ship = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("ship");
    shipRig = ship.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate () {
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W)) {
        shipRig.AddForce(speedUp);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.S)) {
        shipRig.AddForce(speedDown);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) {
        shipRig.AddForce(speedLeft);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {
        shipRig.AddForce(speedRight);
    }

}
```

Comment: Does setting the drag to a value other than 0 not work?

Comment: @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé I tried setting drag to 1 after i let go of the key, but I also want the ship to go in other directions. The drag interferes if I want to move the ship in the other directions.

Comment: Using an opposite force is the simplest course of action here. This is a typical mechanics problem, determining how much deceleration is required to stop an object over a set period of time (and hence how much force should be applied over that time). Have you taken a physics course before in school?

Comment: Have you tried giving the ship a vector3 for travel/movement? if you did you alway apply the travel/movement vector to the ship in your update loop but when you want to move forward  instead of adding your speedUp to the ship you add it to the vector3 for travel/.movement..

Comment: @Serlite I tried adding an opposite force but it stops it immediately and I want it to glide to a stop. And no I have not take a physics course yet.

Comment: @racorse if you wanted to have it slow down at the same rate it sped up at you would want to add the inverse of your speedUp (shipRig.AddForce(-speedUp)) after all, there is no such thing as decelerating, only accelerating in a negative direction.

Comment: @racorse It is a good practice to put the answer outside of the question so that when people are searching for similar problems to yours they are able to see that the question was answered even if it way by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using physics, you just need to apply enough force according to player input to make the ship move as you want. You could set the drag to begin with and keep it that way but make the input force bigger so that you can override the drag.

If you do this, the drag will always be there and will naturally slow something down if there is no force acting on it. If the player presses W, we apply a force *big enough* that will overcome the drag and propel the ship forwards; when they release W, the only "force" acting will be the drag, which will slow it down.

This is an alternative approach to Serlite's comment of using an opposing force.

Newton's First Law of Motion:

> In an inertial reference frame, an object either remains at rest or
>   continues to move at a constant velocity, unless acted upon by a
>   force.

In your case, the only force you have is being applied by the input. You either need an active opposing force in the form of `AddForce` or resistance in the form of friction or drag.

If you want the ship to slow to a halt in exactly 0.5 seconds, you will need to calculate how much drag vs how much velocity the ship has when the player releases the button but if you will accept something "close" to 0.5 seconds you can just get there will some trial and error.

Comment: Just as a side thought, op could also in the update loop do a check to see if a key is being pressed and if it is op can not add the drag to the ship.

Comment: That seems like an unnecessary step to me. Why not just set it as default and leave it?

Comment: @AnselFaillace I did that but it interferes with the other directions when I add them in the future.

Comment: @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé You are right, it is in large part is unnecessary. The reason I stated this as a possible option is because some people like to see only what they are currently affecting it with instead of everything that is affecting it.

Comment: @racorse How did it interfere with your other directions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all the physics calculations MUST be inside the `FixedUpdate ()` and not the `Update ()` function, as by its own nature the Update function happens after a variable time and can happen from 30 to over 200 times every second. This makes it extremely unreliable when it comes to balancing speeds, forces and other physics calculations.

To have it decelerating you can add some drag or apply an opposite force, as already mentioned by Flaming Zombie.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on that!

Comment: No worries, just keep it in mind for the future. It saves you a lot of headaches. ;)